# How to set correctly my routes files (url) with symfony2.5 with WAMP server

Tags: symfony, url, routes, http-status-code-404, wampserver

I set my **route files** in my *Symfony2.5* project. But i have this problem when I launched my application with **Wamp** server (**localhost** on Windows):

```
No route found for "GET /" (from "http://localhost/girSymfony/web/")
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

This is the **url used** when the application is **lauched** on **WampServer**: `http://localhost/girSymfony/web/`

When I tried with this **URL** `http://localhost/girSymfony/web/`I have the 404 error as mentioned above.

But if I try with this url: `http://localhost/girSymfony/web/gir/homepage` it works; I would like the application arrive and run directly on this url. How can i do that?

This is my `Gir/WelcomeBundle/Ressource/config/routing.yml` file **code**:

```
girWelcomeBundle_HomePage:
  pattern:  /homepage
  defaults: { _controller: GirWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index }
  requirements:
    methods: GET
    schemes:  https
```

And this my `app/config/routing.yml` file code:

```
GirWelcomeBundle:
    resource: "@GirWelcomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /gir
```

And here's my controller code for `Gir/WelcomeBundle/Controller/HomePageController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Gir\WelcomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

    class HomePageController extends Controller
    {

        public function indexAction()
        {
          return $this->render('GirWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index.html.twig');
        }
     }
```

Like you can see, I set the routes files, but I just forgot something because I have the 404 error.
I think my application don't use the right **direction** and the right **URL** , how can I fix it ?

**New edit:** *Note that I 've **set WAMP and Symfony** in order when I run my application I arrive directly on the **HomePage index***

Comment: when you use a prefix you default route is (develop environment) http://localhost/girSymfony/web/app_dev.php/gir/ or http://localhost/girSymfony/web/app_dev.php/gir/homepage (be care with the "/" at the end...)

Comment: even if I use or not "/", I have the same error. In fact, If I remove `/homepage` in `gir/WelcomeBundle/Ressource/config/routing.yml` and `/gir` in `app/config/routing.yml` my application goes directly on the index `HomePage`. I would like to do the same thing by setting the URL correctly.

Comment: you can try to delete the https requirement? (I can see the { _controller: girWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index } the name of this bundle is incorrect (**G**irWelcomeBundle)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake when I edited this post, but in my project the name is correct. Even If I remove the **https requirement**, nothing change.

Comment: you know you have two routings.yml (one in app/config and the other is  in your config folder inside your bundle). Furthermore, the order of your "urls" inside your routing.yml is very important, take care with it. You can put the whole file? (app/routing.yml, bundle/resource/config/routing.yml and the controller)

Comment: The whole files are already here. I have just start the application.

Comment: check: /web/app.dev (the appKernel is false), check /web/app_dev.php (the appKernel is true), clear the cache (php app/console cache:clear -e=dev) and try this url "localhost/girSymfony/web/app_dev.php/gir/homepage". And if you need without "/hompage" you need to create a new routing for this url!

Comment: if I change the file like you told me I have another 404 error. in fact I woul like the application arrive/run directly on this url: `http://localhost/girSymfony/web/gir/homepage`. For now I have to write her in my browser, how can I do to make that?

Answer (score 0):

You are on development environemt , you should  have to use url like this

> Example:
>       registration:
>
> > ```
> > pattern:  /registration
> >     defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Registration:registration }
> > http://localhost/girSymfony/web/app_dev.php/registration
> > ```

Comment: Could you explain me correctly what is the difference between development environement and prod environement? If I remove `/homepage` in `gir/WelcomeBundle/Ressource/config/routing.yml` and `/gir` in `app/config/routing.yml` my application goes directly on the index `HomePage`. I would like to do the same thing by setting the URL correctly.

Comment: hey we add app_dev.php in url  for dev env.

Comment: I know that I use app_dev.php for dev env, I set Wamp in order to work. I search the difference but in theory. Thank you.